# Client server multi-threaded application

Tags: c#, multithreading, communication

I want to ask what is the best way to create a client server application .. The data that will be transferred from Server to client will be of a maximum of 15000 Bytes/Session (15 Kb)

and the Client to the server is 5000 Bytes/Session (5 Kb)

In the update that I'm looking forward to (after having the application up and running) .. More traffic will be transferred .. The data will be client-to-server*number_of_session_initiated (minimum 8 Million Sessions distributed)

What I have now:

Server 80% complete, the answer here will help me finish it 100% .. The client is under construction .. But will take a lot from the server since they work the same but with some limitations.

for the code, I get the time (GMT) using the code below

```
DateTime time = DateTime.UtcNow;
string format = "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt";
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(format));
```

output and data sent to client/server is based on input.

So, can anyone guide me to the best way to have a multi-threaded client/server application that can handle many threads?

NOTE: The threads will be on the server side only. The client can open one session only with the server, but the server can communicate with multiple clients at a time.

And what is the maximum number of threads that can be created?

Best Regards.

**EDIT**

Forgot to add .. All data will be sent encrypted so the server/client will have load to encrypt/decrypt (still haven't decided yet on the encryption mechanism).

Comment: Your server is 80% complete and now you ask what the best design is?

Comment: This question is too vague for any useful answer other than "use IIS as your server".

Comment: @HenkHolterman : I meant that the missing part is the communication between the server and client. Rather than that everything is set. The database, the design the input validation. Everything.

Answer (score 2):

The .NET solution to Client server multi-threaded application is [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx). The maximum number of threads that can be created is limited by the WCF host OS, if your going to host the Server in IIS then you can use AppPool settings to manage your threads, if you chose to self-host the WCF in a Windows Service you can make your own thread management in code.

WCF offers several encryption mechanism more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137.aspx).